# Is there any easy way to check for duplicates in a text file in Python?

Tags: python, text

There's one last feature I want for my bank account system.

I want it to check if a username has already been saved to the text file database. If the username already exists, then it should tell the user that they can't have that name option. If not, then they would be able to use it.

The rest of my code works as it should, it's just the fcat that I can't append/update my text file properly and see if usernames already exist in the text file database.

```
import sys


users = {}
status = ""

# Functions ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Select either account creation or login
def displayMenu():
    global status

    status = input("Are you a registered user? \n1 - Yes \n2 - No \nQ - Quit \n")  
    if status == '1':
        oldUser()
    elif status == '2':
        newUser()
    else:
        print("Unknown input error, exiting . . . .")
        sys.exit(0)
    return status

# Account creation 
def newUser():
    global createLogin
    createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

    if createLogin in users: # check if login name exists
        print ("\nLogin name already exists!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw # add login and password
        print("\nAccount created!\n")
                                                #---- Storing the username in a txt file
        file = open("accountfile.txt", "a")
        file.write(createLogin)             
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
        oldUser()



# Account login 
def oldUser():
    global login

    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")


    # check if user exists and login matches password
    if login in users and users[login] == passw:
        file = open("accountfile.txt", "r")
        for text in file:                           ######## This is where I'm trying to compare username duplicates
            if text in file == createLogin:
                print("Username already exists!")

        print("\nLogin successful!\n")
        Bank_Account()     
    else:
        print("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")
        print("Restarting. Please enter details correctly . . . . .") 
        sys.exit(0)




class Bank_Account:

    def __init__(self): 
        self.balance=0
        response = ''

    def deposit(self):
        try:
            amount=float(input("Enter amount to be Deposited: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter digits only")
        else:
            self.balance += amount 
            print("\n Amount Deposited:",amount) 

    def withdraw(self):
        try:
            amount = float(input("Enter amount to be Withdrawn: "))
            if self.balance>=amount: 
                self.balance-=amount 
                print("\n You Withdrew:", amount)
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter digits only")
            s.withdraw() 
        else:
            print("\n ")


    def display(self): 
        print("\n Remaining Balance=",self.balance)






displayMenu()

s = Bank_Account() 

# Calling functions with that class object 
s.deposit() 
s.withdraw() 
s.display()
```

Comment: check out numpy.loadtxt() this gives you an array that you could check.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks you are are writing the user input in the file `accountfile.txt`. So after a few users log in it might look something like:

```
$ cat accountfile.txt
mike
sarah
morgan
lee
```

The section of your code in question is here:

```
file = open("accountfile.txt", "r")
for text in file:
    if text in file == createLogin:
        print("Username already exists!")
```

This particular part is probably not doing what you think it's doing:

```
if text in file == createLogin
```

...
`if text in file` is returning either `True` or `False`.
...
So the line above is essentially saying

```
if False == createLogin
```

or

```
if True == createLogin
```

I believe what you want to do is check if a name is in `accountfile.txt`. The smallest change you could make to your code in order to achieve that would be

```
file = open("accountfile.txt", "r")
for text in file:
    if text.strip() == createLogin:  # .strip() will clean up the \n
        print("Username already exists!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing to the text file, try pickling the database.
This will save a representation of the object that you can easily load back into your program.

```
import pickle

users = {}

users["Ash"] = "password"
pickle.dump(users, open("users.p", "wb"))

loaded_users = pickle.load(open("users.p", "rb"))
print(loaded_users)
```

A more advanced solution may also be to check out a relational database, such as [sqlite3][1]

Comment: I've tried running it and the last line gives me an invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

This line: 
`if text in file == createLogin:` is where you are making a mistake. The line is essentially saying:
  "(if the text is in the file) compare the result of that check with the string createLogin". 
i.e. `if (True/False) == createLogin`, which is always false because the True/False boolean primitives are never equal to any string (if it actually runs, i have not tested to see if an exception will be thrown).

what you should do is this

```
for text in file: # get one line of text
      if createLogin == text.strip(): # compare the line with the user input string 
         print("Username already exists!")
         break
```

`.strip()` removes any leading or trailing spaces in the database stored name (in this case the line break character `\n` used to denote the end of a line in the file. `break` ends the loop prematurely cos your lookup is complete since you found what you were looking for, and it would be an unnecessary to continue comparing the user input with other strings, imagine the txt had 1000 names and the 1st name was a match, the user would see the error printed but the program would continue running for the rest of the 999 tries, making it seem sluggish and waste unnecessary CPU cycles.

The database is still case sensitive however which may or may not be desired depending on your requirements. For case insensitivity you could do the following:

```
for text in file: # get one line of text
      if createLogin.lower() == text.strip().lower(): # compare the line with the user input string 
         print("Username already exists!")
         break
```

`.lower()` makes both strings into lower case strings and then checks if they are the same, eliminating the case sensitivity.